# DisplayMemberPath is not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox

I want to display `CustomerList\CustomerName` property items to the `ListBox` using `ItemsSource` `DisplayMemberPath` property only. But it is not working. I do not want to use `DataContext` or any other binding in my problem. Please help.
My code is given below:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace BindingAnItemControlToAList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerList 
    { 
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public List<string> CustomerName { get; set; }
        public List<string> CustomerLastName { get; set; }
        public CustomerList() 
        { 
            Customers = new List<Customer>();
            CustomerName = new List<string>();
            CustomerLastName = new List<string>();
            CustomerName.Add("Name1");
            CustomerLastName.Add("LastName1");
            CustomerName.Add("Name2");
            CustomerLastName.Add("LastName2");

            Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = CustomerName[0], LastName = CustomerLastName[0] });
            Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = CustomerName[1], LastName = CustomerLastName[1] });
        } 
    } 
}

**MainWindow.Xaml**
<Window x:Class="BindingAnItemControlToAList.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingAnItemControlToAList"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CustomerList x:Key="Cust"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="Grid1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cust}}"  DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName" Height="172" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,23,0,0" Name="lstStates" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" />
           </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your're not setting a "collection" as the ItemsSource...thus you don't get anything to choose from. This will choose the list `CustomerName`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cust}, Path=CustomerName}" 
    Height="172" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,23,0,0" Name="lstStates" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" />
```

But really, you should restructure your `CustomerList` class...there's no need to have separate lists that copy the `Name` and `LastName` fields of the `Customer` - it means you are duplicating data unnecessarily, and also it's possible for the data to get out of sync with each collection.

You also should consider using INotifyPropertyChanged, and use INotifyCollectionChanged on your classes (e.g. use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`, and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Customer` class) if it's possible to change the collection or data.

e.g.

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public CustomerList()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Name1", LastName = "LastName1" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Name2", LastName = "LastName2" });
    }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cust}, Path=Customers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Height="172" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,23,0,0" Name="lstStates" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things off here.  First, your source is set to the object, but the actual list is a property `Customers` of the object.  So you need to use `Source={StaticResource Cust},Path=Customers}`.  Second, the `DisplayMemberPath` needs to be a property of the item, which in this case is `Customer` -- so you have to use *Name* instead of "CustomerName".  This works:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cust},Path=Customers}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: I didn't know that Path can still be used with ItemsSource alongwith DisplayMemberPath. Your suggestion worked just fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My final take from this discussion: To bind an ItemControl we need to take care of 3 properties: 1. Source - it will be the x:Key [class name] that will contain the collection property (in my case, Cust). 2. Path - it will be the property that contains collection (in my case, Customers) 3. DisplayMemberPath - the actual property that is to be displayed (in my case it is, Name).